# What's the purpose of bypassing remapping in Thunderbolt driver?

Tags: macos, dma, iokit, kernel-extension, iommu

My question is just for curiosity, I'm not a developer of MacOS Thunderbolt drivers so I have no experience with that. 
I've come across [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/HardwareDrivers/Conceptual/ThunderboltDevGuide/DebuggingThunderboltDrivers/DebuggingThunderboltDrivers.html) page about thunderbolt drivers and IOMMU on MacOS. From what I've understood, when the driver asks for a memory address, the address obtained is not physical but it is a virtual address mapped by the IOMMU. I think this is due to the security risks of using DMA without a IOMMU. However there are some option for a driver to bypass remapping, for example calling an `IODMACommand` object’s `initWithSpecification` method with `mappingOptions` set to `kBypassed`. However in the page it is said that calling a method like that to obtain an unmapped physical address and use that for DMA will break the driver. 
So my question is: in a thunderbolt driver, what's the purpose of asking for unmapped physical address if that address cannot be used for DMA? 
Sorry if this question may seem dumb, but like I said I've no experience with this kind of stuffs, I'm just very curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no reason to do this *in a Thunderbolt driver* because as you say the Thunderbolt device only gets to "see" addresses in the IOMMU's virtual address space.

You'd use unmapped addresses if you were writing a driver for something that interfaces with system memory using *real* physical addresses from the perspective of the CPU. There's not much opportunity for 3rd party developers to do this type of thing on a real Mac, but when writing drivers for (para-)virtualised "hardware" in VMs, or presumably, when writing drivers for Hackintoshes, there are certainly situations where you're talking to a real or virtual device or service which is not "behind" an IOMMU - usually, this means anything not on any PCIe bus.

For example, [I used the `kIOMemoryMapperNone` option to `IOMemoryDescriptor:: getPhysicalSegment()`](https://github.com/pmj/virtio-net-osx/blob/cd0d520d14b994bca9b1cf9790767a774bfe3c1b/VirtioFamily/VirtioMemBalloonDevice.cpp#L210) in my driver for the Virtio memory balloon. The memory balloon device is really some code on the VM host which operates on VM-CPU-physical page addresses, so if there's a (virtualised) IOMMU in the virtual machine system, sending the memory balloon "mapped" physical addresses would not have the intended result.